# Django models multiple query handling exception

Tags: django, django-models

I have a view that saves data in multiple models, as there are numerous relations.

```
Model1.object.create(**name)
Model2.object.create(**name)
Model3.object.create(**name)
```

Currently im using try except for each model.
Is there a way to handle exception for all these in a better way?

Comment: Not sure what you want here. Answer would depend upon how the exception in a model creation affects the further model creation. If you want to stop them, then enclose everything in a single try-except block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to handle that is using the [Design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract), instead of the [Defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) one. In your case, that means you can verify the integrity of the data passed as argument and handle possible errors before calling the create method, making sure you only call those methods in situations were no error will occur. This way, there is no need for try-except